# android studio date picker not on dialog

Tags: android, datepicker

How can I create a Date time picker that is not on a dialog. Do you guys have an idea? Like this[image]

Any suggestions could help alot. Thanks!

Comment: You can try the [WheelPicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker) library.

Comment: check my ans  my friend

Comment: @KunalChawla - This library is cool man! Thanks alot!!!

Comment: Try this link : https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Answer (score 4):

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:spinnersShown="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add below line in your xml file.

```
<DatePicker
   android:id="@+id/datePicker"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:calendarViewShown="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/date_picker"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:spinnersShown="true"
android:calendarViewShown="false"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

private OnDateChosenListener mListener;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().
            inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_picker, null);
    //Set an initial date for the picker
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //Set the date now
    datePicker.updateDate(year, month, day);

    //create the dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    //set the title
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.date_picker_title))
            .setView(datePicker)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.picker_confirmation, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // do some stuff with the date
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}


// from an Activity...
DatePickerFragment dialog = new DatePickerFragment();
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
```

for more information follow this link [Datepicker Android](http://emuneee.com/blog/2014/09/10/datepickerdialog-on-android/)